# trouble making vertical line with class selector css

Tags: html, css

Im sure this is crazy simple so I apologize for the silly question but I can't get a black vertical line to show up on my site. Here is the code I have:

```
'''html:
  <body>
  <img src="icon-01.png" class="logo">
  <p class="textlogo">Rob Reyes</p>
  <div id="vl"></div>
</body>'''

'''css:
.vl {
margin-left: 100px;
width::10px;
height:100px;
background-color: black;
}'''
```

stylesheet is linked and all other styling seems to be working. Whats going on here?

Comment: your html has id `vl` and your css selecting a class.

Comment: Your question has some formatting errors. Please see [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on how to format code in your posts.

Answer (score 1):

There are two colons after the `width`. There has to be one colon. So you have to remove the extra colon to work it properly.

And you are selecting `class` instead of `id`. Check your CSS selector.

Change in your CSS.

```
#vl {
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Or, change the HTML attribute.

```
<div class="vl"></div>
```